# Disassemble python byte-code

Tags: python, pycharm, disassembly

I'm using python 2.7 and I have a very simple script

```
def simple():
    print("It's simple!")

x = "Come on"
```

Then I import this script in one project like this in order to disassemble him

```
import marshal
import dis


pyc_file = open('./simple.pyc', 'rb')
magic = pyc_file.read(4)
date = pyc_file.read(4)
code_object = marshal.load(pyc_file)
pyc_file.close()
dis.dis(code_object)
```

and get an output

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object simple at 0x7efc5d1bfc30, file "/home/svintsov/PycharmProjects/www.artour.com/simple.py", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (simple)

  4           9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Come on')
             12 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

But I also tried another way of disassembling in another project:

```
import dis


s = __import__("simple")
dis.dis(s)
```

which gives another output

```
Disassembly of simple:
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ("It's simple!")
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

What's the reason these outputs are different? One of them doesn't seem to recognize string literal.

Comment: The first appears to be disassembling the entire script, where the contents of the `simple` function are hidden behind `<code object simple at 0x....>` in the output. The second one is disassembling only the `simple` function itself.

Comment: @Blogbeard If you give an answer, why don't you give an answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm actually gonna answer my question myself.
As python 2.x documentation says

> dis.dis([bytesource]) Disassemble the bytesource object. bytesource
>   can denote either a module, a class, a method, a function, or a code
>   object. For a module, it disassembles all functions. For a class, it
>   disassembles all methods. For a single code sequence, it prints one
>   line per bytecode instruction. If no object is provided, it
>   disassembles the last traceback.

So this function does different kinds of disassembly with respect to "raw" code objects and modules, despite the fact that the bytecode (.pyc file) is the same.

Comment: Well, it didn't really do different *kinds* of disassembly - you passed different input, so you got different output.  If `def simple` contained an inner function, that inner function's disassembly would not be displayed either: http://pastebin.com/TFa3wftH